# How can i create a submenu using the DOM in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, list, dom, button

I'm trying to create a submenu, so that when the item on the menu line is clicked then a submenu will appear along with all its values.

I've created a label along with a div to illustate it.

Once the label is clicked, another div needs to produce another list of items, i haven't got a clue how to do this. Please help !!

```
 <script> 
 var div = document.createElement("div");
 var lbl = document.createElement("label");
 lbl.innerHTML = "Menu";

div.appendChild(lbl)

btn.onlclick = function() {
    var alert = prompt("This button works");
};
```

The list works but i need to show up when i click on the label

```
  (function() {

  var outerUL, li, innerUL, thirdLI, index;

  outerUL = document.createElement('ul');
  for (index = 0; index < 5; ++index) {
    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = "SubMenu" + index;
    if (index === 2) {
      thirdLI = li;
    }
    outerUL.appendChild(li);
  }

  innerUL = document.createElement('ul');
  for (index = 0; index < 3; ++index) {
    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = "Subsubmenu #" + index;
    innerUL.appendChild(li);
  }
  thirdLI.appendChild(innerUL);

  document.body.appendChild(outerUL);

})();      

  document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Any Suggestions ??

Thank you

Comment: Specify what kind of trouble you have with the list.
maybe upload the code to jsfiddle?

Comment: What kind of troubles are you having? A question should include error messages, expected/actual behavior. WTH is up with this line `btn.innerHTML = div.appendChild(btn)`?

Comment: When you can't explain the problem it is a sign that you should step back and explain what you are trying to do.  Most likely there is a better way.